# Postgresql - Delete Lines From jQuery Mobile

Tags: php, postgresql, jquery-mobile

Im in the process of making a jQuery mobile app version of my clients current website.
They have a postgres database that stores users favorite addresses, and they want users to be able to delete saved addresses in the app as well.

Ive looked into many solutions but am unsure what would be the best way to go and was hoping someone could give me some feedback.

I was originally thinking of somehow pulling the saved names from the database into a dropdown list and the unique id into the id of each option in the list and have a delete button underneath. But I cant have the page refresh as all the data in the form will be lost.

My next idea was to try set up a CRUD table, and just to show the saved name column and the delete button next to it. But they're all setup to work with MySQL, would it be difficult to get it to link with a Postgres database instead?

[This](http://lightswitchhelpwebsite.com/Blog/tabid/61/EntryId/126/A-Full-CRUD-LightSwitch-JQuery-Mobile-Application.aspx) is almost exactly what I need but the site Im doing is hosted on a Linux server.

Im basically after some feedback and ideas on how I should look at doing this, any advice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to consider few questions here:

I. How are you going to communicate with you web site?

You can use ajax and JSON/JSONP to communicate with your web server. You need to create a light web service (JSON, not a SOAP protocol) on your server side. Think about what functionality of your mobile app and consider what kind of data you need to transmit/receive.

[JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) is here only for cross domain communication. If you are going to create a mobile app (android and iPhone) then you can use some other protocols but this will require some native coding (if you don't like/know JAVA or Objective C skip this part, JSON will be enough).

II. Now client side story. You can create an object and store all server side data into it or you can use CRUD table. CRUD table is fastest option (if you do it correctly also a fastest option). [jTable](http://www.jtable.org/GettingStarted) is an excellent CRUD framework. It dont care about your server side DB type. Server side will query all needed data and send it in JSON format.
When you have all your data on the client side load it into jTable framework and do with it what ever you want. When you finish your client side editing send back only delta data (only a differences before and after data modification). This will lower your data size.

III. Your idea about selectbox and delete button is great if you are going to delete more then one address info at the same time. There's no need for page refresh because jQuery and jTable will do it without refresh. When you remove/add elements from selectbox just do this:

```
$('#selectBox').create('refresh');
```

It will refresh your select box and applay new css formating to it.
If you want to delete it one buy one it is better to use a listview, it will look much better.

IV. One more thing, you need to consider that jQM lists and select boxes (dropdown boxes) are not built to handle large amount of data. The can hold a lot of it but create('refresh') on large data set will freeze you application. So consider paging.